# angular `ag-grid` custom comparator RowNode coming as undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a column definition as follows:

```js
...
 },
 {
                headerName: 'xyz-header',
                field: 'field1',
                filter: 'set',
                cellRenderer: (params) => this.renderService(params),
                keyCreator: (params) => params.value.label,
                comparator: (label1, label2, node1, node2) => this.compareServices(node1, node2)
 },
 ......
 
function compareServices(node1: RowNode, node2: RowNode): number {
        const li1: ItemVO = node1.data;
        const li2: ItemVO = node2.data;
        let compare = li1.field1.label.localeCompare(li2.field1.label);

        if (compare === 0) {
            compare = li1.revision - li2.revision;
        }

        return compare;
    }
```

```html
 <ag-grid-angular id="id11" class="ag-strap services-grid" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                [rowData]="data.lineItems" (cellValueChanged)="gridValueChanged()" (cellEditingStarted)="setDirty()">
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

Everything else is working fine except the `RowNode` is undefined when it comes to the `compareServices` function. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you turn on the ag-grid sorting? [enableSorting]="true"

Answer (score 0):

There is one argument missing in your comparator function signature.
`comparator: (valueA, valueB, nodeA: RowNode, nodeB: RowNode, isInverted)`